# css position setting of Responsive content

Tags: css, responsive

I am trying a make a responsive website with multiple column of content boxes.

Each content box contain a photo, a title and a caption.

To be short, I want each of them to be displayed in this format 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ST9pD.png

[X] : Image
ABC : Title
xxx : Caption
To specify, I want the Title and Caption to be displayed one by one in web view.

While the Caption will be hide in mobile view, and the Title will be on top of the Photo.
Be notice that the length of Title can vary and become very long that takes multiple lines.
like this: **i.stack.imgur.com/ejElB.png** (sorry not enough reputations to post more than 2 links)

i have tried for days, 
i can only achieve what i want in mobile version, which i stick my title to the bottom of the photo.
However, i cant figure out how to adjust the position of title/capion div to display them properly in web view.
What i done so far: (the mobile view was successfully finished, adjust the window to see)
https://fiddle.jshell.net/1esew8dj/1/

I learnt the stuffs myself all the time, so sorry if it is off standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is already pretty far in achieving your goal. Just add a second div with the title outside the image-box that only displays when not mobile and hide the original title.

Like [this](https://fiddle.jshell.net/1esew8dj/2/) (I only did one box)

**UPDATE:**

It can actually be done much easier, by placing the textBox outside the imageframe, and placing it inside when mobile, using absolute positioning. Like [this](https://fiddle.jshell.net/1esew8dj/5/)

Comment: that's exactly what i want, thank you very much !!

Comment: No problem. Mind accepting my answer if it helped you?

Comment: accepted, thank you very much.

Comment: No problem at all!

Comment: can it be solved without duplicated title?

Comment: actually, that turns out to be not that hard. See my updated answer